# grouping files in java by file name

Tags: java, file, grouping

I have a set of files, thousands of files. Let's say this files are like :

```
abc a 
abc bnd nm 
abc vcb 
abc 
abc something 
nmn as 
nmn af 
nmn bvf
```

I need to group those files. I need to group this files by partial name match. So, in this example I will have 2 groups. One will be the group [abc] and the group [nmn]. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand. Could you give some examples?

Comment: Ok, some files examples : Anti-NSA protesters march through San Francisco (pictures) -  Page 2.txt, Anti-NSA protesters march through San Francisco (pictures) - Page 3.txt, Anti-NSA protesters march through San Francisco (pictures) - Page 4.txt this ones needs to be identified as a group. Another example : Philips BT2500 product photos - Page 2.txt, Philips BT2500 product photos - Page 3.txt also this ones needs to be grouped together.

Comment: Are you manipulating `Strings` that represent file names?

Comment: Yes, the file names are manipulated as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Turns out there's a method in `String` that makes this much easier than regex: `String.startsWith(String prefix)`

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

Regex is useful, but overkill for something like this. My bad for overthinking this at first...

(old answer below)

Sounds like a job for regex!

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

`String.matches()` would help too.

Basically, you'll want to create regexes that match the first sections of your file names and then anything else following those. In the example in your question, example regexes would be "abc.*" for abc______ and "nmn.*" for nmn_____. These probably aren't 100% correct syntax, but that's the general idea. The rules in the link (look at the `Pattern` class) would give you pretty much all you need.

What you'd do is create two new `Sets`, one for each prefix. Then loop through the original set, and based on the regex put the file name into one set or the other.

Comment: I don't know the pattern from the beginning. The file names can be anything. The grouping must be dynamic. I tried a trie algorithm but i get Java Heap Space.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't follow. Does `String.startsWith()` not work? Or do you mean that you have to have the program figure out the prefixes?

Comment: yes, the program have to figure out the prefix. There are 30.000 files having different prefixes.

Comment: Hmmm, an arbitrary prefix might be quite difficult to figure out... Is there any way of distinguishing the prefix from the rest of the file name? In your example names, there's a dash for Anti and a space for Phillips

Comment: I only provided  2 examples from a list of aprox 30.000 files. Things are random. From that random list of files, i need to figure out how the files can be grouped together.

Comment: Are there any patterns you can use? Or is it up to you?

Answer (score 0):

create a hash map of `String` as key and list of `File`(in case you want to store file object) or `String`(in case file name)

and check if name starts with `Anti` put it in group 1 with the key whatever you like
starts with `Philips` put in group 2 with the key whatever you like